# preload/include polymorphic associations for a Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :parent # parent/children from the gem awesome_nested_set
  has_many :children # 
end

class Car
  has_many :comments
end
```

owner can be a `Team`or a `User` or a `Group`. Each of them is having attributes `name`, `avatar`(carrierwave) and `created_at`

#### the problem:

we do use `ActiveModel::Serializer` for our response. (`CommentSerializer`). inside the serializer we defined `belongs_to :owner` and `has_many :children`.

```
render json: car.comments
```

this is working great, but it is far away from performing well, considering a set of 100 comments (and most of them have childrens). so we have an easy lookup of 300+ User/Team/Group associations.

how can we pre-load them? i was thinking on something like

`car.comments.include(:children, :owner)`but how is this working for a polymorph association?

```
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 37 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (3.1ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 39 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (10.6ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 40 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 41 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 42 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 43 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 44 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 45 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   Team Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
[active_model_serializers]   Action::Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `comments`.`parent_id` = 61 ORDER BY `comments`.`lft`
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (5.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `users`.`id` = 8 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (95.65ms)
```

**Completed 200 OK in 111ms (Views: 70.3ms | ActiveRecord: 34.8ms)**

This is actually the output for a total of 10 comments